# always get The input was not found in the haystack in zf2 select element

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new in zf2

I am always getting the error `The input was not found in the haystack` when I have select a language from a drop down. Here's my code:

In my controller

```
function singleAction(){
—
—-
—-
$language = array();
$languages = $this->getManageTable()->getLanguage();

foreach($languages as $lang){
$language[”] = ‘Select Language';
$language[$lang[‘id_language’]] = $lang[‘name’];
}
—
—-
—-
return new ViewModel(array(
‘form’ => $form,
‘language’ => $language,
));
}
```

Inside manageForm.php :

```
// Language Input
$language = new Element\Select(‘language’);
$language->setAttributes(array(
‘id’ => ‘language’,
‘class’ => ‘form-control’,
));
$this->add($language);

$language = new InputFilter\Input(‘language’);
$language->setRequired(false);
//$language->removeValidator(“NotEmpty”); // not working giving error
// not working giving error:
//$language->setAllowEmptysetRegisterInArrayValidator(false); 
//$language->setErrorMessage(‘Please select language’);
$inputFilter->add($language);
```

In my View I called like so:

Language

```
<?php echo formSelect($form->get(‘language’)->setValueOptions($language)); ?>
```

Now when I submit without selecting value from drop-down working fine..

..but if I select some language and submit, I get this error `The input was not found in the haystack`.

I checked my language data I am getting in post but if `($form->isValid()) {—-}` gives me an error.

How can I resolve this, I checked lot of links but haven't found any solutions. Please help me. I don't want to validate this drop-down element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oho Thanks God,

I got the solution

Inside manageForm.php  :

```
    $language = new Element\Select('language');
    $language->setAttributes(array(
            'id' => 'language',
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ));
    $language->setDisableInArrayValidator(true);
    $this->add($language);
    $language = new InputFilter\Input(‘language’);
    $language->setRequired(false);
     $language->setErrorMessage(‘Please select language’);
   $inputFilter->add($language);
```

That it, it is now working fine. May be it will help someone.
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
$this->add(
            array(
                'type'=> 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
                'name' => 'language',
                'required' => true,
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'value' => 'en' ,
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
                    )
            ));
```

Comment: 'disable_inarray_validator' => true -- worked for my situation. Thank you for the post!